# how to locate bug in code rather than memory address in Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift

I was watching the Stanford Swift course(C193P). The professor was doing a demo. When the iOS program crashed the bug was located in the code. But when I do this as the professor, the bug was located automatically in memory address even if I set the breakpoint. How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Did you add exception breakpoint ?

Comment: @suthar I tried but didn't work. Actually I watch the whole video and the professor didn't do any breakpoint operation, but the bug automatically located in code.  I have no idea why I can't.

Comment: Do you have a url of that video ?

Comment: @suthar https://youtu.be/gjl2gc70YHM?list=PLxwBNxx9j4PW4sY-wwBwQos3G6Kn3x6xP  time: 48:00, thank you very much.

Comment: Make sure you have "Always show disassembly" unchecked: http://i.imgur.com/axTI2pT.png  But note that you can't always prevent the disassembly from showing.  If an exception happens in a *compiled* library that you don't have the source code for, you'll get this every time.

Comment: Do you have Xcode set via Menu : Debug : Debug Workflow : Always Show Disassembly? If so uncheck that.

Comment: I'll check after 4 hours then i'll let you know, if you find any solution then let me know

Comment: @suthar I unchecked "Always show disassembly" and it's ok now. thank you all the same

Comment: @mnbvxz Consider accepting answers that are helpful. 

Voting up a question or answer signals to the rest of the community that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful, while voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information.

Click on the hollow checkmark next to the answer that is best.  [See this page for more detail](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have "Always Show Disassembly" checked in this menu:

[image]

Then the debugger will always take you to the disassembly code.

Turn off this option.  It's found in the menu:

> Debug > Debug Workflow > Always Show Disassembly

---

Note that there is no option for "New Show Disassembly".  If an exception occurs deep within a compiled library that you don't have the source code for, or if you're stepping into code with the debugger, you can always find yourself ending up in the assembly code.